Combining two code pages in one program in C
I am making a program that reads from a file that has characters from two different alphabets (Cyrillic and German). However, when printed to the terminal, ö, ä and ü come out as ?.
So far, I have tried:

using system("chcp 1251")
changing the encoding of the file my program reads from

Is there any way for the program to read the characters from both alphabets? Is there some 'mixed code page' I have missed out on?
Code:
void readG(){
    system("cls");

    // open the file in read mode
    fptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\pl\\projects\\sources\\lernwortschatz.txt", "r");

    // print title
    printf("LERNWORTSCHATZ\n");
    printf("A1\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");

    // read and print the file's contents
    while(fgets(str, 10000, fptr))
    {
        printf("%s", str);
    }

    // close the file
    fclose(fptr);
}

Example:

What is expected: ergänzen - попълвам
What comes out: erg?nzen - попълвам

What I am trying to do with the file:
I want to get all of its contents and then immediately print it without saving.
Part of the result in bytes:
30 20 2d 20 4d 65 69 6e 65 20 57 3f 72 74 65 72 
20 69 6d 20 4b 75 72 73 0a 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 
2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 
2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 61 6e 73 65 68 
65 6e 20 2d 20 e2 e8 e6 0a 64 61 73 20 42 69 6c 
64 2c 2d 65 72 20 2d 20 ea e0 f0 f2 e8 ed ea e0

Here is a part of the file the program reads:
ansehen - виж
das Bild,-er - картинка
hören - слушам
noch einmal - още един път
ankreuzen - зачерквам/попълвам

Here is this part of the file in hex representation:
00000000: 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d2d 2d0d 0a61 6e73  -----------..ans
00000010: 6568 656e 202d 20e2 e8e6 0d0a 6461 7320  ehen - .....das
00000020: 4269 6c64 2c2d 6572 202d 20ea e0f0 f2e8  Bild,-er - .....
00000030: edea e00d 0a68 3f72 656e 202d 20f1 ebf3  .....h?ren - ...
00000040: f8e0 ec0d 0a6e 6f63 6820 6569 6e6d 616c  .....noch einmal
00000050: 202d 20ee f9e5 20e5 e4e8 ed20 effa f20d   - ... .... ....
00000060: 0a61 6e6b 7265 757a 656e 202d 20e7 e0f7  .ankreuzen - ...


In what encoding is the file to begin with? That makes all the difference here. How are you reading the file?

The file that gets read is in Windows 1251 and I am reading the file with the fgets() function.

Use a tool or library to read the files in whatever encoding they have, and convert to UTF-8?

A file encoded in Windows-1251 can't contain the glyphs ö, ä and ü, because they do not exist in that codepage.

@Someprogrammerdude That's skimming over the fact that e.g. strlen() and friends won't do the Right Thing in UTF-8 (especially this question is about non-7-bit characters), so that'd involve quite some more complexity...

remember that an old school text terminal can only display 1 codepage at a time! And that's what C was and is designed for

Show an example of the file, preferably with the hexdump, and show how one can differentiate between the Cyrillic and German characters of the same code point in different charsets? Or are they actually in Unicode? And also show your code

If you have a file that is mixing Windows-1251 and Windows-1252, then it's going to be very hard to know when character 0xFD is ü and when it's э.

What are your goal with the files and the texts? Only to print immediately? Do some processing? Something else? Please give us as many details of the original and underlying problem you need to solve, to make it easier for us to give you a suitable solution.

Perhaps include some bytes of the input file so we can see what we're actually dealing with here? Perhaps od -tx1 lernwortschatz.txt | head -n 8 if you're on unix

If you're not on unix (it seems like you're on windows) you could change your code from printf("%s", str)tofor(int i=0; str[i]; i++) printf("%02x ", str[i]); printf("\n");`  to display bytes rather than the string contents. Paste some of the result into the question.

@phuciv Firstly, added code with example. Secondly, I have no idea what a hexdump is. Finally, what do you mean by how one can differentiate between the Cyrillic and German characters of the same code point in diffrent charsets?

How do you put ergänzen - попълвам in a file? "I have no idea what a hexdump is" You need to google it, because you cannot do your work without knowing your essential tools.

@Someprogrammerdude added what my intention to do with the program is.

@PaulHankin added part of the result in bytes.

@phuclv added hex representation

"What I am trying to do with the file: I want to get all of its contents and then immediately print it without saving." Well, that should work just fine if you run your program and redirect into a file (e.g. myprogram.exe > foo.txt). However, your terminal can't interpret the bytes you're trying to output, and that's why you're getting ?s.

The hex dump is the input file or the result of you copying the output from the terminal?

There is no ergänzen in your hex dump. Please show how a file with this specific word looks.

So, the file you have indeed does have two different single-byte character encodings on each line. That's quite the technical feat to have managed with any regular text editor! :)
Let's take the hören line 68 3f 72 65 6e 20 2d 20 f1 eb f3 f8 e0 ec as an example, but I'm going to modify it a bit because the hex dump you're showing is already broken; the byte 3F is the question mark, not what would be ö in ISO-8859-1 (F6).
I'm going to use Python to illustrate the problems you'll face because it's good at dealing with various encodings.
>>> x = '68 f6 72 65 6e 20 2d 20 f1 eb f3 f8 e0 ec'
>>> b = bytes.fromhex(x)
b'h\xf6ren - \xf1\xeb\xf3\xf8\xe0\xec'

If we just decode the hexadecimal encoding of those bytes into a bytestring, we can see its Python representation, where all of the printable 7-bit ASCII bytes are shown as themselves, but everything else is shown as an escape sequence. Don't be fooled, this is not human-readable text, it's just a sequence of bytes that partially looks readable.
Alright, so let's try to decode this into text as ISO-8859-1 (aka latin-1) (which is near to the CP1252 codepage).
>>> b.decode("latin-1")
'hören - ñëóøàì'

We can see that the ö for hören was decoded well, but the Cyrillic is unreadable mojibake.
Let's do it the other way, then:
>>> b.decode("cp1251")
'hцren - слушам'

The German turns out a bit unfortunate, because the byte \xf6 is interpreted as ц in CP1251 but the Russian checks out (according to Google Translate anyway).
So – if we were using Python, we'd decode this by splitting it and decoding each half:
>>> de_bytes, _, ru_bytes = b.partition(b" - ")
>>> (de_bytes.decode("latin-1"), ru_bytes.decode("cp1251"))
('hören', 'слушам')

(and this indeed prints out just fine on my Mac's terminal, and would also do so in Python UTF-8 Mode on Windows).
Now, back to C land: the issue is that fgets() and friends don't give a darn about encodings – they're all just bytes (though fgets() knows that the byte 0x0a (10 in decimal) is the newline character in ASCII encoding, and stops reading there).
When you read those bytes, you get exactly those bytes, and it's up to your app to interpret them. When you output those bytes using printf() on your regular Windows terminal, it will use the current console output codepage to translate the bytes into glyphs.
Technically, you could output these files correctly in your Windows terminal with something like

read a line
switch to codepage 1252 (SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);)
write out each Latin byte until you find space-dash-space
switch to codepage 1251 (SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);)
write out each Cyrillic byte until you're out of this line

... rinse and repeat.
Another option would be to read your input into Unicode codepoints, e.g. UTF-8 or UTF-16. You'd still have to interpret each half of the lines differently, and UTF-8 in particular is a variable-width encoding, so you can't trust strlen() to give you the actual human-eyes length of a string anymore, but at least your playing ground would be level enough so you could use some of the answers in Properly print utf8 characters in windows console.

First check your code page on console with typing chcp. It will shows your active code page. E.g. Active code page: 437
Type chcp 65001 on console. (65001 – UTF-8 Unicode)
Now it is UTF-8 compatibility.
In your code, you can use wchar.h for fgetws and fputws
It is also be note that BYTE_COUNT is not wide-character count. It is byte count in the file.

E.g. пъ it consists 2 of wide-characters but also has 4-bytes
你 it is a wide-character but has 3-bytes

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define BYTE_COUNT 100

void readG(){
  FILE *fptr = fopen("file.txt", "r");

  printf("LERNWORTSCHATZ\n");
  printf("A1\n");
  printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");

  wchar_t str[BYTE_COUNT ];
  if(fgetws(str, BYTE_COUNT , fptr) != NULL) {
    fputws(str, stdout);
  }

  fclose(fptr);
}


OP's file doesn't have wide characters.
